# Allow sorting=false is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my grid view i wants to insert new records to the last row of grid view. so i set `Gridview2.Allowsorting` is `false`. but it doesn't works on my grid view. my code is here

```
 public void gridview2_selectgroup()
{
    if (Session["selectedgroupes"] != null)
    {
        ArrayList groups = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList student_id_list = new ArrayList();

        groups = (ArrayList)Session["selectedgroupes"];
        student_id_list=(ArrayList)Session["STUDENT_ID"];

        string select_string="SELECT student_name,student_id,student_nric,student_group FROM student_details WHERE student_group='"+groups[0].ToString().Trim()+"' ";
        for(int i=1;i<groups.Count;i++)
        {
            select_string+= " or student_group='"+groups[i].ToString().Trim()+"'";    
        }

        if(Session["STUDENT_ID"]!=null)
        {

        for(int i=0;i<student_id_list.Count;i++)
        {
            select_string+= " or student_id='"+student_id_list[i].ToString().Trim()+"'";    

        }
        }
        SqlConnection con = obj.getcon();
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select_string, con);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        GridView2.DataSource = ds;
        GridView2.AllowSorting = false;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
```

what will be the reason? It works on another grid views on my project . please help

Comment: What you want to Correct/ happen when you set AllowSorting=false ?

Comment: What does the code look like on one of the grid views that works correctly?

Comment: i wants to show newly inserted records on bottom of gridview. but now it shows on sorted format . i wants to avoid that sorting @FlopScientist

Comment: the difference is, just the select query changed. @Brian Rogers

Comment: What if you set allowsorting=false before you databind?

Comment: Show your insert process and full gridview markup

Comment: there is no insert process. just selecting values from already existing  table. is that the problem??? !!  @ FlopScientist

Comment: Ok so you are just performing the select query and grid view is showing it sorted always ???

Comment: yes ! please help @ FlopScientist

Comment: I guess, if the only code regarding the select query is as above, then check your database first. May be it contains the data sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your gridview in .aspx page and hit f4. The properties window will popup. There u check the 5th line (Allow Sorting).If its true make it false. Sometimes the codebehind code will not work due to timings.If its already false then place your "GridView2.AllowSorting = false;" in between datasource and databind.

```
GridView2.DataSource = ds;
GridView2.AllowSorting = false;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

Comment: i have done like you suggested. but even it doesn't works @Sasidharan Chandran

Comment: did u check .aspx page for <asp:GridView ID="" 
    AllowSorting="false" CssClass="datagrid" GridLines="None">

Comment: yes. i have tried that way too. failed . is the problem with select command? ! Iam just selecting records from a table to grid view.       @ Sasidharan Chandran

Comment: give a break point in that query and copy the whole query and paste it here.Let me see how it is framed.Even then if there is some problem with query we will try stored procedures.

Comment: if u dont want sorting, remove that gridview2.allowsorting=false.Bcoz default value for allow sorting is false.remove that and check.and also do u recieve any warnings or errors.

Comment: i have tried i by avoiding allowsorting=false. but defaultly it performs sorting. i wants to avoid this sorting.so that i can insert the " NEW RECORDS TO THE LAST ROW OF GRIDVIEW "                        @ Sasidharan Chandran

Comment: then for sure u have some messy around ur select query.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string select_string="SELECT student_id,student_name,student_nric,student_group FROM student_details WHERE student_group='"+groups[0].ToString().Trim()+"' ";
```